# add space in parameter and SET/P

Tags: batch-file

How do I pass a parameter to a function that is only a space, without passing quotes.

And how to add a space as  ECHO|SET/p=" %*"  removes the first space

```
CALL :echoNoLinefeed  !countDeleted! File(s) deleted 
GOTO :exit

:echoNoLinefeed
  REM  Echo a line without a linefeed
  ECHO|SET/p="%*  "
  GOTO :exit

:exit
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify the language you're asking about. It looks like you're asking about Batch, but it's good to specify.

Comment: It's the `ECHO|SET /p="%*  "` that's stripping out your space.  Can you use a normal `echo` statement like `echo %*` instead?